# Do all US vice presidents get cool jackets?

Tags: nasa, history, space-art

The Ars Technica article [Vice President may tell NASA to accelerate lunar landings](https://arstechnica.com/science/2019/03/vice-president-may-tell-nasa-to-accelerate-lunar-landings/) starts with

> "We're tired of generating PowerPoint journeys that don't go anywhere."

and explains that one or more members of the National Space Council believe that if NASA's schedules are dramatically shortened then everything will be "better".

> Several sources have previously told Ars that Pence is dissatisfied with the pace at which NASA is progressing back toward the Moon. For example, when he and Trump came into the White House in 2017, NASA was targeting 2019 for a test launch for the Space Launch System rocket. Now that is not likely to occur before 2021.
>
> "I think 2028 is so late-to-need that it doesn't even need to be on the table," Griffin said of NASA's Moon plans. "Such a date does not demonstrate that the United States is a leader in anything. This is 2018. It took us eight years to get to the Moon the first time, and you're going to tell me it takes 10 to 12 to 14 to do it again when we know how?"

For more on the role of the Space Council see answers to [What is/will be the function of the United States National Space Council?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/22154/12102)

---

But my focus is on the cool jacket that the vice president is wearing. Is this a standard item produced for each vice president (who traditionally has a special role in NASA and US science policy because... (citation needed)?

Do all US vice presidents get cool jackets? Or is this a new phenomenon?

[image: US vice-president's NASA jacket]

[image: US vice-president inspects NASA sans jacket]

US vice president sans jacket, on a previous vice-presidential inspection of NASA. From [Satellite manufacture and cleanliness](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/23792/12102)

Comment: There is at least one vice-president who should get free clean room gloves.

Comment: They just made a name tag and velcroed it on to an astronaut jacket. Shameless pandering. Similar jackets on the Kelly twins: https://compote.slate.com/images/e1f698f4-dcf3-4a8e-b2f7-8d4f64c64a41.jpeg?width=780&height=520&rect=1560x1040&offset=0x0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**New**

It would seem that the vice president receiving a spiffy jacket is a new phenomenon.  However, quite a few presidents have received some version of a flight jacket.  I think it's safe to say shameless pandering will happen regardless of who is in office.  It's a small price to pay for the chance of greater funding.

[image: Trump]

[image: Obama]

[image: Clinton]

[image: Reagan (Seems he didn't get a patch with his name, but rather received a jacket honoring John Young and Robert Crippen's STS-1 flight)]

Comment: The question was about vice presidents with cool NASA jackets, but you only found presidents with NASA jackets.

Comment: @Uwe re-read the first sentence; "It would seem that the vice president receiving a spiffy jacket is a new phenomenon."

Comment: @ben `+1` great answer, thank you for looking into this!

Comment: *Shameless pandering [...] to secure more funding...* God that is a ***majorly depressing*** sentence.